# MapReduce in Relational database management system (RDBMS)

Tags: database, nosql, mapreduce, relational-database

How come I've never heard of the term [MapReduce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce) when using relational database (RDBMS)? And now suddenly with [NoSQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) MapReduce is everywhere. I would just like to understand in general sense why there's no MapReduce concept in relational database and why NoSQL needs it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging by what the Wiki article you linked to has to say, MapReduce is an implementation technique.  One of many possible others.

The relational model was invented precisely so that implementation techniques could be **abstracted away** from the user.

It is quite telling that certain people now start "movements" that promote **exposing** the implementation techniques again to the user, and it is even more telling that they call that "progress".

People who know and understand the relational model, also understand that in a truly relational DBMS, there is nothing to stop the engine from applying exactly those very same MapReduce techniques **under the covers**, when dealing with "BigRelations".

Answer (score 0):

https://www.coursera.org/#course/bigdata